# Huawei 6851 can not advertise /32 subnets in BGP

Tags: huawei

I have a Huawei 6851-48s6q and i have a few vlanif interfaces and 2x ip transit connected to this switch,
i have set a few public ip on those vlanif like as 213.x.x.1/29 and 213.x.y.33/29 and here is my bgp config

```
route-policy DT-Blackhole permit node 10

 apply local-preference 450

 apply community 12345:666

 apply preference 255

 

 route-policy IPTRANSIT-OUT permit node 10

 if-match community-filter Blackhole

 apply community 98765:666

 

 ip community-filter basic Blackhole index 10 permit 12345:666



 bgp 12345

  ipv4-family unicast

  preference 120 110 255

  network 213.x.x.1 255.255.255.255 route-policy DT-Blackhole
```

when i execute display bgp routing 213.x.x.1/32 i can see that and here is the output:

```
display bgp routing-table 213.x.x.1
 BGP local router ID : 172.x.x.14
 Local AS number : 12345
 Paths:   2 available, 1 best, 1 select, 0 best-external, 0 add-path
 BGP routing table entry information of 213.x.x.1/32:
 Network route.
 From: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)
 Route Duration: 0d00h18m10s
 Direct Out-interface: 40GE1/0/1
 Original nexthop: 127.0.0.1
 Qos information : 0x0
 Community: <12345:666>
 AS-path Nil, origin igp, MED 0, pref-val 0, valid, local, best, select, pre 0
 Not advertised to any peer yet
```

here is interface vlan config:

```
interface Vlanif684
 ip address 213.x.x.1/29 255.255.255.248
```

i can not configure out why does 213.x.x.1/32 is not announcing to my ip transit, i checked my route-policy many times and other prefixes are working properly just the assigned ip to the vlanif is not announced,

Answer (score 3):

You can only advertise networks that exist in your RIB, and they can only be advertised as whatever the mask is in the route entry. So, if it’s a /29 network, you have to advertise it as a /29. If you want to advertise a /32, you need to add a route (real or null, depending on where it needs to go) onto your device so it’s in the RIB, and then BGP will announce the route.

Comment: i added /32 route with null0 but it does not activated in RIB the assigned ip to the vlanif is activated

Comment: @Blackmetal Can you please update your post with what you added?

Comment: you can see interface vlanif 684 config, i want to announce 213.x.x.1/32 to my iptransits and blackhole it

Comment: @Blackmetal Okay, but what you have above in BGP is .0, not .1.

Comment: i paste it wrongly, i just correct it.

Comment: @Blackmetal Maybe I’m missing something. You said that was your BGP config, but now you’re saying you pasted it wrong (which means it would have had to be wrong before you copied it).   Can you just provide your full sanitized config?  And you can’t hide your IP addresses otherwise we won’t know if you entered something wrong.